# Play Framework evolutions not working with Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, playframework

I am using java-play-spring template (obtainable here: https://github.com/jamesward/play-java-spring#master )and currently I am trying to write some evolutions for it.

I am putting my script:

```
 # --- !Ups

CREATE TABLE accounts
(
  accountid INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  clientid INT NOT NULL,
  credit DECIMAL(13,2)
);


# --- !Downs

drop table accounts;
```

into conf/evolutions/default/1.sql. Unfortunatelly, after application starts, nothing happens. I suppose that it may be Spring/Hibernate fault, so i disabled Hibernate validation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("models");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE);
        entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

But this didn't help. I have also added

```
play.modules.evolutions.enabled=true
```

To my application.conf. This does not help too.

Does anyone has any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: I could be mistaken.. but i don't believe evolutions will work with hibernate... since play expects hibernate to handle migrations automatically. See the highlighted section [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/evolutions) ... the link is old however, the newest documentation doesn't mention anything to this regard.